# Unselect checkbox when clicked on other

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I have following JS code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Package(yCheck){
document.getElementById(yCheck).checked=!document.getElementById(yCheck).checked;
}
</script>
```

and following HTML code

```
<p><input type="checkbox" id="booster1" /><br /><a onclick="Package('booster1')">Select Pack 1</a></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="booster2" /><br /><a onclick="Package('booster2')">Select Pack 2</a></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="booster3" /><br /><a onclick="Package('booster3')">Select Pack 3</a></p>
<p><input type="checkbox" id="booster4" /><br /><a onclick="Package('booster4')">Select Pack 4</a></p>
```

Now when I click on any text below the checkbox it select the checkbox above. However what I also need to add is when other checkbox is select, the first one will be unselected. What changes I need to make inside JS code?

Thanks for help

Comment: why not use a radio buttons

Comment: radios developed for such work better to use those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using radio buttons as per my example below:

```
<input type="radio" id="booster1" name="name1"/><br /><a onclick="Package('booster1')">Select Pack 1</a></p>
<p><input type="radio" id="booster2" name="name1"/><br /><a onclick="Package('booster2')">Select Pack 2</a></p>
<p><input type="radio" id="booster3" name="name1"/><br /><a onclick="Package('booster3')">Select Pack 3</a></p>
<p><input type="radio" id="booster4"name="name1" /><br /><a onclick="Package('booster4')">Select Pack 4</a></p>
```

When you want to select one among multiple then it is always better to use radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

Do not mess up with `checkboxes`.As all suggested in comments Radio group is the perfect suite to your functionality.

http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/adding-a-radio-button-group-to-an-html-form/